# Converting function from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration, plpgsql

I am working on converting something from Oracle to PostgreSQL. In the Oracle file there is a function:

```
instr(string,substring,starting point,nth location)
```

or as it is in my file

```
instr(string,chr(10),instr(string,substring),1)
```

In PostgreSQL this does not exist, so I looked up an equivalent function. I found:

```
position(substring in string)
```

but this does not allow the starting position and the nth location parameters.

Is there anyway to make this function start at a given point? Or is there a better function to use in PostgreSQL where I can specify starting position and the nth location?

This would have to work on PostgreSQL 8.2.15 because that is the version we are running on the database.

Comment: There is `substring(string [from int] [for int])` if you need to operate on part of the string. Perhaps there's easier solution, but you didn't show us your input or expected output.

Comment: Are you sure about version 8.2.15? 8.2 is EOL since December 2011, and you're also missing 8 minor versions: The latest 8.2 version was 8.2.23. Your version has many serious (security) issues. Do yourself a favor and upgrade to a recent version asap.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function `strpos(str, sub)` in Postgres is equivalent of `instr(str, sub)` in Oracle. Unfortunately, the function does not have third and fourth parameters, so the expression in Postgres must be more complex.

The function `substr(str, n)` gives a substring of `str` starting from `n` position.

```
instr(str, ch, instr(str, sub), 1);                               --oracle
strpos(substr(str, strpos(str, sub)), ch) + strpos(str, sub) - 1; --postgres
```

As `instr()` is a powerful function I wrote it in plpgsql for my own needs.

```
create or replace function instr(str text, sub text, startpos int = 1, occurrence int = 1)
returns int language plpgsql immutable
as $$
declare 
    tail text;
    shift int;
    pos int;
    i int;
begin
    shift:= 0;
    if startpos = 0 or occurrence <= 0 then
        return 0;
    end if;
    if startpos < 0 then
        str:= reverse(str);
        sub:= reverse(sub);
        pos:= -startpos;
    else
        pos:= startpos;
    end if;
    for i in 1..occurrence loop
        shift:= shift+ pos;
        tail:= substr(str, shift);
        pos:= strpos(tail, sub);
        if pos = 0 then
            return 0;
        end if;
    end loop;
    if startpos > 0 then
        return pos+ shift- 1;
    else
        return length(str)- length(sub)- pos- shift+ 3;
    end if;
end $$;
```

Some checks (Examples from [OLAP DML Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564)):

```
select instr('Corporate Floor', 'or', 3, 2);  -- gives 14
select instr('Corporate Floor', 'or', -3, 2); -- gives 2
```

There is no `reverse()` function in Postgres 8.2. You can use this:

```
-- only for Postgres 8.4 or earlier!
create or replace function reverse(str text)
returns text language plpgsql immutable
as $$
declare
    i int;
    res text = '';
begin
    for i in 1..length(str) loop
        res:= substr(str, i, 1) || res;
    end loop;
    return res;
end $$;
```

Comment: instr function not correct, care if you copy it:
instr('1aba2bab3', 'aba', -1)  results 3 should be 2; 
instr('1aba2bab3', 'ab', -1)  results 7 - correct; 
instr('1aba2bab3', 'b', -1)  results 7 should be 8; 
instr('1aba2bab3', '3', -1) results 8 should be 9;

Comment: @Ice2burn - thanks, there was a mistake in the last `return`, corrected.

Comment: All good now, thank you. Was looking for RightPos function, your solution was the only one I've found

Answer (score 2):

**The simplest form:**

```
instr(string, substring) ::= strpos(string, substring)
```

**With a `position` parameter:**

For a positive `position` value:

```
instr(string, substring, position) ::= strpos(substr(string, position), substring) + position - 1
```

For a negative `position` value:

```
instr(string, substring, position) ::= strpos(substr(string, char_length(string) + position + 1), substring) + char_length(string) + position
```

**With an `occurrence` parameter:**

This does not exist in PostgreSQL. You don't seem to need it (example gives `occurrence = 1`) but if you do then you need to write a function that recursively works on sub-strings extracted from the second version.

**So:**

```
instr(string,chr(10),instr(string,substring),1)
```

becomes

```
strpos(substr(string, strpos(string, substring)), chr(10)) + strpos(string, substring) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***split_part()*** function in postgres

Refer to the following link

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('A,B,C', ',', 2);
```