# Postgresql function similar to Find() in Excel?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How can I find the position of a string starting from a specified index in Postgresql-9.3+

Example

```
find('ranranran','an',1) should output 2
find('ranranran','an',3)  => 5 
find('ranranran','an',6)  => 8
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059437/converting-function-from-oracle-to-postgresql I think this could be usefull for You.

Comment: Have you read any of the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html)?

Comment: @muistooshort yes I have but there is no straight forward function.

Comment: @Patryk thanks I think that may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had found answer to this, just want to post it.

```
strpos(substr('withintext',pos),'texttofind') + (pos-1)
```